Troubleshooting Slow Execution Times in PostgreSQL for Data Aggregation Query
I'm currently dealing with a complex SQL query in PostgreSQL, aimed at aggregating financial data across multiple tables, each containing millions of rows. Despite my efforts to optimize the query by adding indexes, I'm experiencing sluggish performance, with execution times stretching far beyond acceptable limits. This performance issue is becoming a bottleneck, affecting our application's responsiveness.
The query successfully executes without any error messages; however, the execution time is exceedingly long, taking several minutes to complete. This is far from the expected performance, given that I have indexed all relevant columns. There's a specific need to optimize this query further to reduce the execution time without compromising the accuracy of the results.
SELECT a.id, a.name, SUM(b.amount) AS total_amount
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.a_id
WHERE a.status = 'active'
AND c.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY total_amount DESC
LIMIT 100;


I aim to significantly reduce the execution time of this query to ensure a smooth user experience. Ideally, I'd like the query to execute within a few seconds, even when operating on a dataset containing millions of records. I'm seeking guidance on advanced optimization techniques, including any specific PostgreSQL features or configurations that could help achieve this level of performance efficiency.

Please update your question to include complete table definition (ddl) and all indexes. Then run  explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) statement; Post the results as text maintaining the indentation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
